# Replace a string template with an HTML link

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Using React and JS, I want to replace this type of text:

```
this is parsed text this is first user @[Robin van den Persie ](Robin) in one line

this is second user @[Didier Drogba ](didier.drogba) in second line


this is third line with a lot of content and this is also this is also this is also this is also this is also this is also ddd
```

..into this:

```
this is parsed text this is first user @Robin van den Persie in one line

this is second user @Didier Drogba in second line


this is third line with a lot of content and this is also this is also this is also this is also this is also this is also ddd
```

And as you can guess those `@FullName` parts needs to be **clickable links** which will point to users profile (url is: `/username`). Username can contain only lowercase letters, numbers and these 3 symbols `-_.`

Template is:

```
@[first and last name](username)
```

I tried to solve this problem with regex in combination with LinkifyJS, so basically, to turn that text above into link which will then be passed into Linkify and I will get simple span with desired content and behaviour.

I tried to write some regex which will match the above mentioned pattern and I got this far:

```
@\[^[a-zA-Z ?]\]\([^a-z0-9-_.]\)
```

But this is not correct and I'm stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your use name can contain lowercase letters only than how you're replacing the first string values ? look at your first string it does contain `Robin`

Comment: Looking at present provided example it seems you're looking for pattern such as `@[some text](some text)` to match

Comment: Be careful to only run regexes like this on plain text, not HTML input, and be careful that your resulting functionality does not open you up to XSS attacks. https://alanhogan.com/html-myths#regex-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```regex
@\[(.+?)\s*\]\(([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)\)
```

And replace with something like:

```regex
<a href="/$2">$1</a>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oEzhwB/1).

**Javascript example:**

```js
const regex = /@\[(.+?)\s*\]\(([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)\)/gm;
const str = 'this is parsed text this is first user @[Robin van den Persie ](Robin) in one line \
this is second user @[Didier Drogba ](didier.drogba) in second line \
this is third line with a lot of content and this is also this is also this is also this is also this is also this is also ddd';

const subst = '<a href="/$2">$1</a>';

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@\[([^\]]+)\]\([^\)]+\)
```

[image]

```js
let str = `this is parsed text this is first user @[Robin van den Persie ](Robin) in one line

this is second user @[Didier Drogba ](didier.drogba) in second line


this is third line with a lot of content and this is also this is also this is also this is also this is also this is also ddd`

let replaced = str.replace(/@\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\)/g, "<a href=\"/$2\">$1</a>")

console.log(replaced)
```

Note:- If you want `[](xyz)` or `[]()` to replace with empty string you can use `*` instead of `+`